# Why '1' and (char)1 are not equal when compared in c++?

Tags: casting, char

My main goal is to convert int to char type. I used `(char)1` to type cast, but it doesn't seem to work due to the following result:

When I compare `'1'` and `(char)1` in c++ in the following code

```
if ('1' == (char)1)
{
    return 1;
}
```

However, it seems that the comparison is either invalid due to different variable type or they are actually not the same thing. I always thought converting integer `1` to character is `(char)1`. Can anyone tell me how I can convert integer `1` to char `'1'`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'1' is equal to (char)49 according to http://www.asciitable.com/

(char)1 is equal to `SOH (start of heading)` which is a non-printable character.

Answer (score 2):

Because the ASCII equivalent of '1' is 49, not 1.

Answer (score 1):

'1' == The character CODE value for the printable 1, traditionally ASCII value, but today, the code point value in whatever charset is used.

The old trick is  (ch - '0') to get the numeric value.

Depending on the language you should use a conversion function for a full string.

C++ - `stoi`, `stol` or `strol` or `stringstream`

C - `atoi` or `atol` (these work in C++ too)

Comment: `ch - '0'` is valid in all character sets for which C++ is supported

Comment: @MattMcNabb Right, I should remove ASCII from the second sentence. When I first looked at the tags, it didn't say C++ so I didn't make any assumptions what language, though I can't think of any other languages where it would differ anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As ibiza said, char(49) is in fact what 1 is. This is because char draws from the ASCII library.

Comment: "This is because char draws from the ASCII library." No. ASCII is not required, though it is the case most implementations. (Furthermore, ASCII is not a library.)

Answer (score 0):

Because when you do `(char)X` with X a number, you are just converting X into the range of a char, either [-128 to 127 or 0 to 255](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm) (like a modulo).

For example, `(char)300` gives `44` (because 300 % 256 = 44) and `(char)1` gives `1`. As said in the others comments, 1 is the ASCII equivalent of SOH (Start of Heading), and not of the character '1'.

Comment: Can I have an explanation about the downvote please ? None of the other comments explained what `(char)1` actually returns.